# Пунктуация. Нужна ли в предложении запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Я хотел бы узнать, нужна ли в этом предложении запятая после **"Вероники"**?

> С каждым новым словом Вероники Сармат все больше слушает и меньше
> говорит.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, здесь необходима смысловая запятая или интонационное тире.

Когда я первый раз начал читать это предложение, мне показалось, что речь идет о какой-то Веронике Сармат (Вероника - имя, Сармат - фамилия). И только потом стало ясно, что Вероника и Сармат - это два разных человека. Поэтому постановка запятой или тире здесь крайне рекомендуется (как минимум для того, чтобы не усложнять жизнь читающему).

Таким образом, можно предложить два варианта пунктуационного оформления данного предложения:

> С каждым новым словом Вероники, Сармат все больше слушает и меньше говорит.
>
> С каждым новым словом Вероники - Сармат все больше слушает и меньше говорит.

Какой из них лучше - решать вам.

*Обновлено: благодаря рекомендациям [@oleedd](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/193755/oleedd), добавлен вариант с интонационным тире.*

Comment: Мне тоже сразу понять не удалось (подумал, что ошибка и должно быть "Вероник**а** Сармат"). В таких случаях ставят интонационное тире, о "смысловой запятой" не слышал.

Comment: @oleedd, интонационное тире было бы необходимо в том случае, если бы с каждым новым словом что-то бы делала Вероника Сармат. А мне сначала показалось, что с каждым новым словом Вероники Сармат, некий неназванный персонаж (о котором возможно велась речь в предыдущей не приведенной здесь фразе) все больше слушает и меньше говорит. Хотя судя по всему, автор имел в виду, что некий Сармат все больше слушает и меньше говорит после каждого слова Вероники. Но в любом случае, данная фраза без дополнительного знака препинания выглядит слишком неоднозначно.

Comment: Интонационное тире, по Розенталю, используется в том числе и для нейтрализации двусмысленности. Не думаю, что тут возможна запятая. Слишком уж тесная связь между фрагментами.

Comment: @oleedd, хочу уточнить: где именно вы бы поставили интонационное тире?

Comment: Между именами, конечно. Да и есть смысловой перелом, то есть, скорее всего, до этого было наоборот. Это как вариант, можно и без него. Но запятая — как-то дико...

Comment: @oleedd, перечитал еще раз. Пожалуй, насчет возможности применения интонационного тире Вы правы. Добавил этот вариант в ответ. Но все же мне кажется, что вариант с запятой тоже имеет право на жизнь. В любом случае, большое спасибо Вам за замечания и конструктивную критику!

Comment: Если здесь был бы один из факультативно обособляющихся обстоятельственных оборотов, тогда да: *Благодаря каждому новому слову Вероники, Сармат все больше слушает и меньше говорит.* Так в чём же разница между такими случаями и такими, как в примере из вопроса? Если оборот является центральным в смысле предложения (как у нас), а не вспомогательным, то он не должен отделяться запятой. На это среди прочего очень влияют предлоги.

Comment: Основной посыл моих комментариев вот в чём: интонационное тире дозволено ставить чуть ли не где угодно, а вот запятую-то нет.

Comment: @oleedd, возможно это мои личные "тараканы", потому что в молодости я очень любил эти интонационные тире, т.к. они в значительной мере соответствовали моим привычкам в устной речи - я любил делать "драматические паузы" в середине предложений. Но после того, как сразу несколько редакторов честно сказали мне, что из-за обилия этих тире мои статьи становится невозможно бегло читать, потому что каждое такое тире невольно заставляет читателя замедлить чтение (и после того, как я увидел, что эти тире они все равно удаляют перед отправкой в печать), я начал стараться отказываться от такого приема.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128200/discussion-between-ivan-olshansky-and-oleedd).

Comment: Как говорится, всего должно быть в меру.

Comment: @oleedd, безусловно.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, запятая не нужна: обстоятельство здесь *необособленное*. [Здесь](https://compendium.su/rus/practical/37.html) перечислены признаки, по которым обстоятельство обособляется; сами увидите, что ни один из них к вашему случаю не подходит.